# Regex to find at least 4 occurrences of forward slash in string

Tags: regex

I have some urls and I would like to make sure they have at least 4 forward slashes as some of my URLS have less. For example:

Pass:
http://localhost:2000/machine/my-test-machine/3

Fail: 
http://localhost:2000/my-test-machine

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Dave

Comment: split by `/` and count resulting array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following regex,

```
\/\/(.*\/){3}
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lN7hQ0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just match it 4 times:

```
(?:.*?/){4}
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/O782VtptZX).

The reluctant quantifier `*?` will ensure that slashes are not skipped over when matching (eliminating back tracking)

<sub>Your regex engine (unspecified) may require the forward slash to be escaped, ie `\/`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead such as:

```
^(?=(?:[^\/]*\/){4,})(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN9tQ5/2)